# Make FTP available to VPN users only (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, ftp, windows-server-2012

I would like to setup a VPN in Windows Server 2012 (interested in 2008 too) - then setup FTP and only allow access to the FTP server for VPN users.

How do I do this - and I presume once a VPN user is connected they wont need further holes in the firewall to access the FTP?

(also would this be the same if using an OpenVPN server instead of built in VPN?)

Answer (score 2):

Configure the Windows Firewall to only allow FTP connections from the subnet that VPN'd users are connected to when they have an active VPN connection.

Comment: thanks - I'm not using windows firewall, I have an external hardware firewall.

Comment: Then configure the hardware firewall to only allow access. If that's not feasible, then turn on Windows Firewall. It's a questionable practice to turn off host-based firewalls because you have a hardware firewall. Depth of defense is an important principle, especially when using something as insecure as FTP.

Comment: Hi - let me flip that - I don't want FTP accessible externally with the only line of defence Windows Firewall. 

Using both I have no problem with.

How do I know what subnet VPN users use - and how can I set that up?